# what repository does sbt 0.13.7 reside in?

Tags: sbt

I'm apparently missing a repository because when I specify sbt version 0.13.7 I get
org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.7: not found

I'm using Artifactory locally to cache all my dependencies, and I need to add the correct repository to my Artifactory.

It also fails to find 0.13.6 but it works with 0.13.5 so I must have already downloaded that version on to my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're still working on moving this into scala-sbt.org, but you can find the artifactory instructions we worked up with JFrog here: https://docs.google.com/a/typesafe.com/document/d/18fGjMz21J4-JMHXfDH4OyGOXu8NvWfsG4q83S9RT64M/edit

Oh, and the repository is repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases (but as an ivy repository)

Comment: Well, with your help I managed to get it satisfy all the unresolved dependencies, so 'sbt update' now works. However, although I specified scalaVersion 2.11.4 in my build.sbt, the scala-library it downloaded was 2.10 instead of 2.11.  When I specify sbt version 0.13.6 in build.properties it uses 2.11 but when I specify 0.13.7 it uses 2.10 (without changing anything else). Is this the expected behavior?